# Is there an API for adding a user to a site?

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2.2

With 2.2, I've begun implementing some write features in my app. I've started with voting. When you vote on a question on a site that isn't in a users associated accounts, you get the error "The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site." That makes sense, but is there a way to add a user to a site with the API? I notice that the official Android app pops up a dialog offering the user a chance to join the site in the same situation. Is that done via a private API?

If this isn't possible, consider this a feature request.

Comment: There isn't; from the [blog post introducing version 2.2 of the API](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/), "User creation is too sensitive to guarantee stability"

Comment: I wouldn't really think of this as "user creation." It's associating an existing user with a new site.